# How to connect MetaTrader with a Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, metatrader4, metatrader5

I'm building a system, based on Node.JS, to connect with MetaTrader and to process all action like link account, open, close trade order...

But I still have not found out the way how to connect with MetaTrader in Nodejs. Can you give me a solution or package examples, that can help me do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

### Observation:

MetaTrader software suite has multiple parts, only one of which is a customer-facing one - the MetaTrader Terminal 4/5. This terminal software communicates with MT4/5 Server and there are many other, additional Broker-side MetaTrader suite, server-cooperating systems.

Given your indication above, you seem to plan for Node.JS functional integration with MetaTrader Terminal piece of software.

### Limitations:

As clarified above, the MetaTrader Terminal 4/5 software platform is the subject of interest and before technical steps are taken, a validation ought take place, so as to confirm, whether programmable features and services, natively supported inside MT4 Terminal are covering all you needs or not.

Given the MT4 Terminal has a programmable ecosystem for both for automated processing and for semi-automated back-testing, these two principal directions do not provide the same level of comfort for integration with an external cooperating logic or event-flow.

Given you project needs are not met with the built-in native MQL4/MQL5 code-execution environment, your further approach will have to be mixed with some GUI-manipulating assistive technologies, which may help to cover the gaps detected in the functional mapping pre-validation phase.

### Approach:

For the purpose of making the MT4 Terminal code-execution ecosystem to cooperate with external worlds, there is a built in ability to **`#import`** extending features, not present in the native MQL4/5 language via DLL-s.

Having received this freedom of design, the user-code in the MQL4/5 language can borrow all missing features and services available for such integration projects.

Both Node.JS and MetaTrader Terminal 4/5 can use **`ZeroMQ`** and/or **`nanomsg`** for a fast and productive integration of a heterogeneous distributed system, which seems to be a match for your indicated needs.

Feel free to read other posts **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20ZeroMQ%20%5Bmql4%5D)**, about signalling/messaging function-plane concepts, used for the sake of this very kind of system integration.